# Como substituir caractere por índice em uma string?

Tags: javascript, string

Quero substituir uma posição dentro de uma string, por exemplo:

```js
a = "@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@";
a[5] = "#";

console.log(a); /* Esperava obter "@@@@@#@@@@@@@@@" */
```

Tentei desse jeito mas a string não atualiza e imprime igual a primeira atribuição.

Se não me engando, é porque strings são imutáveis. Então como eu crio essa nova string e atribuo a `a` novamente?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

De fato, strings são imutáveis e não é possível alterá-las desta maneira.

O jeito é construir outra string, mudando apenas o caractere que você quer.

Uma solução é usar o [método `substring`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring) duas vezes: uma para pegar tudo antes do índice a ser alterado, e outra para pegar tudo depois. Algo assim:

```js
var a = "@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@";

var posicao = 5; // posição que você quer trocar
a = a.substring(0, posicao) // tudo antes da posição
    + '#'  // caractere que será trocado
    + a.substring(posicao + 1); // tudo depois da posição

console.log(a);
```

---

Há também outras soluções:

- uma regex que pega tudo antes, tudo depois e troca somente o caractere da posição indicada (na minha opinião, desnecessariamente mais complicado que usar `substring`)
- fazer um *loop* pelos caracteres da string: se for a posição indicada, troca, senão usa o mesmo caractere
- criar um array contendo os caracteres da string, trocar a posição desejada, e juntar os elementos do array em outra string

```js
var a = "@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@";

var posicao = 5; // posição que você quer trocar

// regex: pega tudo antes, tudo depois e troca a posição por #
var r = new RegExp(`^(.{${posicao}}).(.*$)`);
a = a.replace(r, "$1#$2");
console.log(a);

// for
a = "@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@";
var nova = '';
for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    // se é a posição, troca, senão usa o mesmo caractere
    if (i === posicao) {
        nova += '#';
    } else {
        nova += a[i];
    }
}
a = nova;
console.log(a);

// cria um array com os caracteres da string, troca e depois converte de volta para string
a = "@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@";
var array = Array.from(a);
array[posicao] = '#';
a = array.join('');
console.log(a);
```

Answer (score 1):

Me aproveitando da resposta apresentada pelo hkotsubo [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/564956/137387), que conclui que strings são imutáveis e o uso do método [`String.prototype.substring()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring) é util para construir uma nova string composta pelas porções relevantes da string original intercaladas pela substituição.

Para não ser tão igual reescrevi o exemplo usando o método [`String.prototype.slice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice):

```js
let s = "0123456789ABCD"; //A sequencia de caracteres foi alterada em relação ao exemplo para facilitar a visualização do resultado.

const i = 5; //Declara o índice em que a string sofrerá alteração.

s = `${s.slice(0, i)}#${s.slice(i+1)}`;

console.log(s);
```

`String.prototype.slice()` possui algumas diferenças para `String.prototype.substring()` como pode ser visto em detalhes [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2243835/11379709).

Continuando, analisando a documentação do método [`String.prototype.replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace):

> **`replace(pattern, replacement)`**
> Retorna uma nova string com uma, algumas ou todas as correspondências
> de `pattern` substituídas por a `replacement`.
>
> *`pattern`*: pode ser uma string ou um objeto com um método [`Symbol.replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol/replace).
> *`replacement`*: pode ser uma string ou uma função.
>
> - Se for uma string, ela substituirá a substring correspondente a pattern...
> - Se for uma função, ela será invocada para cada correspondência e seu valor de retorno será usado como texto de substituição...

O símbolo `Symbol.replace` nos permite personalizar o método de substituição de strings no método `String.prototype.replace()`.
No caso é possível fazer, com que o método `String.prototype.replace()` retorne as porções relevante da string original já intercaladas por um caractere de substituição utilizando o procedimento já conhecido.

```js
/**
 * Instancia um objeto de substituição de caractere por índice.
 * parâmetro idx tipo numérico inteiro é índice onde será realizada a substituição.     
 */
function Substituir(idx) {
  this[Symbol.replace] = (s, r) => {
    return `${s.slice(0, idx)}${r[0]}${s.slice(idx+1)}`;
  }
}


let s = "0123456789ABCD";

const i = 9; //Declara o índice em que a string sofrerá alteração.

s = s.replace(new Substituir(i), "#");  //Substitui o caractere de índice i por #.

console.log(s);
```